# Why can't I edit the html of a page on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to modify a the html of a wordpress page, but the text button isn't working. When I checked my console, I get this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token: load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery…:420
```

I have checked other pages and console doesn't have these errors. I'm not really experienced on php/wordpress, so I'm not really sure what to look for. I checked the load-scripts.php file, but didn't get any clue, and the file itself looks like its working because before the error, and on other pages, there's a console log that seems to come from that file:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery…:9
```

Also, this is WordPress 4.5.5

[Link to problematic file](http://papelitobrasil.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,sug&load%5B%5D=gest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,wp-a11y,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,wp-p&load%5B%5D=lupload,mediaelement,wp-mediaelement,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edit,svg-painter,wp-&load%5B%5D=auth-check,jquery-ui-tabs,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,media-upload,jquery-ui-po&load%5B%5D=sition,wp-pointer,editor,wplink,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete&ver=4.5.5)

Comments requested the html of the text button

```
<button type="button" id="content-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="content">Texto</button>
```

[image: Image showing the page]
Thats the page: in case you wonder, "páginas" means page

What I have tried: I went to the `wp-includes/js/` folder, and changed the name of the files: `hoverIntent,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response` and their minified versions. The only one I didn't change was common, because it wasnt there. I expected it to give me a different error, or even break, but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: What page/file specifically? None of this is my code, I'm just trying to fix someone else's site

Comment: HTML code from your text button. Did you try to change something in the JS file ?

Comment: I added the html code from the text button, but I don't think thats the problem. The problem seems to be something being invoked. I did not try changing any of the JS files yet, I don't know which one is causing trouble

Comment: No. The problem has nothing to do with the button. The problem is some javascript file is malfunctioning, preventing the button to work. I don't know what file, and which specific part of the file. I added a link to the problematic file on the question

Comment: pd: I know what file, but the file is generated on the go, I think, so I don't know what is the original file

Comment: It could be an error from a custom JS file, not the JQuery file. You can't find which one it is ? Or maybe the script has been set directly on the HTML file on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You have a Javascript error somewhere in the scripts that are being loaded into the admin. This is most likely from one of the plugins installed.

First, update all of the plugins. The little orange circle with the "8" in it means that there are 8 plugins that are out of date. It is possible that the fix will be in one of those updates. After you update, test to see if your problem is fixed.

Second, add `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` to the `wp-config.php` file in the web root. This will tell WordPress to not modify or combine the admin area scripts and allow you to debug the issue. Sometimes this alone will fix the issue since the concatenation process sometimes finds scripts that are not properly formatted and break when modified this way. So again, test after doing this.

Finally, if the above two options don't fix it, the error message you get in the console should now be able to at least point you to the correct file to find the issue in since they are no longer combined into one big file.

Comment: Do you know where the files are? I ended up fixing it changing the html I wanted to change after the page loaded with javascript, but I'm inclined to do it the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn;t store Page or Posts as HTML files. All of them are generated dynamically using your database and your theme’s template files. My best guess is that you are looking for a way to change your theme’s template files which is normally done via a child theme.

Comment: Wordpress gives you the option to edit Pages and posts as HTML when you clicked the "Text" option, as the image I just added shows. The theme is fine, I just need to edit one specific page, because I need to add a field to a form.